# UINavigationView strange black shadow

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a navigationController, when i push a new view using segue, i show this strange black shadow, how can i solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: just set navigation bar transclucent to no

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

Comment: but the navigation bar become white and loss actual color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's something under your navigation controller; make sure you haven't extended in your view controller the edges under the top bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling translucent works.
[image]

And I found that this will decrease views in navigation bar, which caused this problem.